# bootstrap data tables on click checkbox checked remain all disabled

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, pagination

In bootstrap pagination i have 100 records, each page showing 10 records, Total 10 pages in pagination.
My requirement is only one check box is checked and allowed remain all check boxes disabled, For example 1st record is checked remain all records disabled, if i want to check 4th record remain all check boxes disabled. only one check box checked through out the total pagination.

Without pagination it is working, with pagination only 1st page is working , if i go 2nd page not disabled .[Without pagination working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ra6ka.png)

[With pagination 1st page working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GT1I0.png)

[With pagination 2nd page not working means not disabled](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8I3Mu.png)

It is working only 1st page click one check box checked remain all disabled in pagination, if go to 2nd page pagination not disabled. can any one give me solution for this. i tried below code.

### Below code is without bootstrap pagination working

```
$(".ta_checked").change(function() {
       this.checked ? $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", true) : $("." + this.className).not(this).prop("disabled", false);
     });
```

### Below code is with bootstrap pagination not working if i go to 2nd page

```
$(".ta_checked").change(function() {
 
   var table = $('#ta_table').DataTable();
   table.$('.ta_checked').each(function(){
      
       $("input.ta_checked").prop("disabled", !this.checked);
   }); 
     }); 
    $("#ta_table").DataTable({});
```